# Retrofit : Send data to server using retrofit

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I being learning about retrofit. I have done create one class that is `login` using retrofit (by following tutorials on internet).

Now, I try to create other process that is `sign up` . I was confused which one that I should change in `login` function. honestly, I can't understand the concepts.

this my several `login`'s code :

UserLogin.java

```
public class UserLog {

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
//getter and setter...
```

RestCallBack.java

```
public abstract class RestCallBack<T> implements Callback<T> {

    public abstract void failure(RestError restError);

    @Override
    public void failure (RetrofitError error){
        RestError restError = (RestError) error.getBodyAs(RestError.class);// create your own class as
        // how the error message gonna showup from server side if there is an error

        if(restError != null){
            failure(restError);
        }else{
            failure(new RestError(error.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

RestError.java

```
public class RestError  {

    public Integer errorCode;
    public String extendedMessage;
    private String message;
    private String moreInfo;
    private Integer status;

//getter and setter
```

SessionRequest.java

```
public class SessionRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    private static final String TAG = SessionRequestInterceptor.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");/*
        you can add header here if you need in your api
        */
    }
}
```

RestLoginCLient.java

```
public class RestClient_Login {

    private static RestApi_login REST_CLIENT;
    private static String ROOT = "http://192.168.10/testapp";


    static {
        setUpRestClient();
    }


    public static RestApi_login get()
    {return REST_CLIENT;}

    private static void setUpRestClient(){
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(ROOT)
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
                .setRequestInterceptor(new SessionRequestInterceptor())
                .build();

        REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(RestApi_login.class);
    }
```

RestApi.java

```
public interface RestApi_login {
            @POST("/user/login")
            void login(@Body UserLog user,
                       RestCallBack<LoginResponse> callBack);
}
```

LoginResponse.java

```
public class LoginResponse {
    public String email;
    public String id;
    public String error;
    public UserLog resp;

    LoginResponse(){}

//getter and setter
```

**Guide me which one code that i should change in order to i can create my `sign up` process**

Answer (score 1):

For login you can follow [this](https://futurestud.io/blog/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit/) link. This gives a step by step idea whats happening in the code also. So you get a idea about what you are doing too.

Comment: how about `sign up` which one of code above that i should change ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you better start using `Retrofit` alone without `OkHttp` firstly.

1) Define your response java `POJO` class.

2) Define your request `interface` class.

3) Set up the `callback` response (success/failure).

4) Define `RestAdapter` and consume your `API` through your interface.

This is the basic approach and the easier.

Comment: i wanna learn by doing. several of these code you said, i have understood (perhaps not expert). when i created project that implements above, i more fast for understand.

Comment: I think if you understood the 4 steps that I described then there should be no problem at all. Your code is a little bit confusing and messed up, and you should redefine the way you will implement your request, response and debug in order to understand what's wrong in your communication and then ask about the piece of code you get any error or bottelneck. But this code is not going anywhere with your question.

Comment: yes, i agree with you. I believe the answer of my question is in my code, haha! but i still searching where is it. even i knowing several steps in describe above, sometimes, i still faced difficulty.